# How to link slightly differing times

Tags: sql-server-2008, join

I have two log tables that I would like to link, but the entries made in each table are not done at exactly the same time and the time difference varies but should always be within a second.

To keep it simple, let's say table A looks like:

```
ItemId int
Comment varchar(50)
LogTime datetime
```

and let's say that table B has the exact same structure.

Suppose these records are in Table A:

```
ItemId    Comment       LogTime
-----------------------------------
100       Test100-A1    12:00:00.00
200       Test200-A     12:00:03.50
100       Test100-A2    12:00:06.30
```

and these are in Table B

```
ItemId    Comment       LogTime
-----------------------------------
100       Test100-B1    12:00:00.03
200       Test200-B     12:00:02.98
100       Test100-B2    12:00:06.53
```

And I'd like to have the following output

```
A.ItemId    A.Comment   A.LogTime     B.ItemId    B.Comment   B.LogTime     
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
100         Test100-A1  12:00:00.00   100         Test100-B1  12:00:00.03
200         Test200-A   12:00:03.50   200         Test200-B   12:00:02.98
100         Test100-A2  12:00:06.30   100         Test100-B2  12:00:06.53
```

How can I create a query that will link the two tables together this way on the ItemId and LogTime, but with up to a 1 second variation in either direction for the LogTime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out... was actually a bit simpler than I realized.

```
select *
from   A left join
       B on A.ItemId = B.ItemId and
            abs(DATEDIFF(ss, A.LogTime, B.LogTime)) <= 1
```

I tried doing it based on milliseconds instead of seconds the first time but that was giving me an overflow error when comparing dates that were too far apart.  I'd rather do milliseconds though so I can narrow it down to a little less than a second but not sure what the best way to accomplish that just yet.  Maybe I could use a case statement.  If someone else wants to post an answer that does it I'll mark it or else I'll come back later and update my answer to work off milliseconds when I get a chance.